# Resize a VM hard-drive (virtualbox)

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, virtualization

Is there a way to resize a VM hard drive? I am using virtualbox and I have a VM that has run out of space, looked into the settings but it seems I may have to  create another partition. I thought there might be an easier way, anyone have an idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the VBoxManage command.

You can see details [here](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/02/how-to-easily-resize-virtualbox-40-hard.html).

Example:

```
"c:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe" modifyhd "C:\Users\busey\VirtualBox VMs\ubuntu10.10\ubuntu10.10.vdi" --resize 20480
```

After resizing hard disk , you will have to resize partition(s).

For ext3 partition you can follow [these](http://www.howtoforge.com/linux_resizing_ext3_partitions) steps.

Comment: [It would be nice](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link only for future reference.

Comment: Yes. I was hoping there was a way through the vbox gui but this does the trick.

Comment: Can you actually include the steps in this answer, instead of simply posting a couple of relevant links? The links may become broken at some time in the future, and then the essential information will be gone (if the steps aren't posted here as well.)

Comment: Do not open command line "as administrator" because you'll get `Code CO_E_SERVER_EXEC_FAILURE (0x80080005) - Server execution failed (extended info not available)`. Run it as a normal user.

Answer (score 5):

This worked on a VHD with a bootable image of Win7:

1. VirtualBox -> Virtual Media Manager -> Copy
2. C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox>VBoxManage.exe modifyhd "c:\VirtualMachines\Windows 7 Large.vhd" --resize 2000000
3. VirtualBox -> VM -> Settings -> release current VHD and mount new VHD
4. Boot VM into Windows
5. Use Computer Management -> Disk Manager -> right-click on partition -> Extend

Comment: What is the host OS in this example? Do these steps apply to any host operating system, or just one specific host operating system?

Comment: Host was Win7 64-bit. Haven't tried it on other hosts.

Comment: Works also on Win8 64-bit with an image of Win8 64-bit

Answer (score 3):

For a `vdi` this worked, the host being Windows 7.

```
c:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox>VBoxManage.exe modifyhd "C:\Users\busey\VirtualBox VMs\ubuntu10.10\ubuntu10.10.vdi" --resize 20480
```

Answer (score 1):

[CloneVDI](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?t=22422) can help do this. You can create a clone of an existing VDI and increase the disk size at the same time. Used this without any problems for a couple of years.

Answer (score 0):

There is an article about this: http://coderjournal.com/2011/07/reducing-the-size-of-a-virtualbox-hard-drive/

Short but sufficient. In short:

- delete temp files (obvious)
- defragment (assuming your guest filesystem can be defragmented)
- use VBoxManage, as other users suggest