# How to resize VirtualBox volume disk with Microsoft Windows?

Tags: windows, virtualbox, partitioning, virtual-machine, disk-space

I have [Apple Macbook (MAC)](https://www.apple.com/lae/macbook/) with 128G volume space.

I received [Virtual Machine (VM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_machine) in [Open Virtual Appliance file (OVA file)](https://fileinfo.com/extension/ova) with size 25G. After import that file in [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) that space grow to 50G. Within my another software from [Adobe Creative Cloud](https://www.adobe.com/creativecloud.html) there was no space left.

When I ran that VM I saw "[Microsoft Windows (MS WIN)](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/cloud-platform/windows-server)" with 100G volume disk and 60G free space. Also bunch of applications what shouldn't be there.

After I try uninstall all apps, disable swap, remove everything not necessary, instead of reduce size VM or be fixed at least, that VM volume grow from 50G to 70G(!).

Q how can I reduce VM properly in my machine?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Resize a VM hard-drive (virtualbox)](https://superuser.com/questions/378041/resize-a-vm-hard-drive-virtualbox)

Comment: @Ramhound possible yes, the same no - I solve exact issue and exact steps to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PRE-REQUIREMENTS

1. if your volume disk file is in another format like "[VirtualBox Virtual Disk Image (VDI)](https://fileinfo.com/extension/vdi)" you have to convert it to VDI
2. also if it's type "Fixed" `--format VDI` we need to set it to "Dynamic" `--variant Standard`

`{{vbox_path}}\VBoxManage" clonehd --variant Standard --format VDI {{input_filename}}.vmdk {{output_filename}}.vdi`

STEPS

1. attach disk like "not SSD"
2. remove all data, temp, turnoff swap, turnoff hybernate, empty trash
3. defragment
4. open "Disk Management" `diskmgmt.msc`
5. shrink volume to space with 1G free
6. from new free space create a new disk, and set "full format", and remove it after format
7. download [SDelete](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/sdelete)
8. on first shrinked volume run `sdelete.exe -c c:` and then `sdelete.exe -z c:`
9. run `{{vbox_path}}\VBoxManage" modifyhd --compact {{output_filename}}.vdi`

Now that volume disk is set to minimum size even if can shown size bigger. Within set minimum size for volume inside operating system MS WIN it cannot grow and that file will be constant. In future when you want bigger then just set bigger size in "Disk Management".

My VM has after that 30G.

I hope it helped someone.